# How to make a link work only if a user is logged in

Tags: html, css, session, anchor

I have an image button on a page which is surround by `<a>` tags to redirect it to another page when that image is clicked. How do I change so that it works only when a user logs in?

The login works because I can see the session come through once the user is in. Basically I want to say if a users tries to click this button without logging in, an alert will display telling them to login.

At the top of the page I have this code:

```
<?PHP echo "Hi " . $_SESSION['first_name']?>
```

A user should only be allowed to click this button once they have logged in (created a session):

```
                <div class="image_button">
                <a href="shop.php"><img src="graphics/shop.png" alt="Shop"/></a>
            </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without any code or any indicator in either HTML or CSS (or Javascript) too see if a user is logged in we can't help you with anything. Please show us the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Apologies, code has been added ^^

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Unfortunately, I don't know PHP well enough to answer this question without Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see if there is a session variable set or not:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['first_name'])) {
  // echo out a clickable image
}
else {
  // echo non-clickable
}
```

Alternatively, you can echo some attribute in the div or on the page after you check for being logged in, then find that with Javascript, and then `e.preventDefault();` on the image to kill the linking.

Answer (score 0):

A generalized approach would be to make the link's functionality conditional on the length or existence of the trimmed session variable.  Pseudocode:

```
<?php
$linkstring="#";
if $_SESSION['first_name'] != "" {
    $linkstring='shop.php';
    }

print '<div class="image_button"><a href="'.$linkstring.'"><img src="graphics/shop.png" alt="Shop"/></a></div>'
?>
```

I doubt this would work as php copied straight out of this block but it's a pattern you can use in ColdFusion-I'm assuming a php server could interpret strings as literals in links.

Edit-I tested this approach on MAMP and it works.  The session variable is going to be the tricky part here.